# class cast exception thrown in string array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, casting

I just append two string array into one array list and then convert it to string array to pass return variable as `string[]`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String [] a = {"america", "bakrain", "canada"};
    String [] b = {"denmark", "europe" };
    try{
        List<String> listString = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(a));
        listString.addAll(Arrays.asList(b));
        String [] outResult= (String[])listString.toArray();
        System.out.println(outResult);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    

}
```

the error comes

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
at myFirst.myClass.main(myClass.java:26)
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: String [] outResult=  new String[listString.size()];
          listString.toArray(outResult);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub          

    String [] a = {"america", "bakrain", "canada"};
    String [] b = {"denmark", "europe" };
    try{
        List<String> listString = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(a));
        listString.addAll(Arrays.asList(b));

        System.out.println(listString);
        String [] outResult= new String[listString.size()];

        int i=0;
        for(String str: listString){
            outResult[i]=str;
            i++;
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    


}
```

Answer (score 3):

You would need to individually cast each member in the array because the result is Object[] not String[]

Or just do

```
String [] outResult= listString.toArray(new String[listString.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
String[] outResult = (String[]) listString.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Answer (score -1):

`listString.toArray();` will return `Object[]`, not `String[]`